# Select option dropdownlist yii

Tags: php, yii

When i select value from drop down list, 
and I submit form, i want my drop down list to have selected value, 
not to be on default value again.
I try like this, but not working:

```
 <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'code', $countriesIssuedList, array('name'=>'countriesIssued'), $select = array($_POST['countriesIssued']));?>
```

Also i would like to add a first value to be default, not from db, i want to do it in the code like this, `array('empty'=>'--Select country--')`
but not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must change the name of your dropdownList you must manually set the value of `code` to `$_POST['countriesIssued']` in your controller/view. As for the default, `prompt` is used to set this.

```
<?php if(!$model->code) $model->code=$_POST['countriesIssued'];?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'code', $countriesIssuedList, array(
    'name'=>'countriesIssued','prompt'=>'--Select country--'
));?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter (currently `'code'`) must be a key in this array: `$countriesIssuedList`

See for example [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh4).

---

"*Also i would like to add a first value to be default*" ... perhaps you can use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

Comment: Sorry you mean something like this, $form->dropDownList($model, array('code'=>$countriesIssuedList), $countriesIssuedList, array('name'=>'countriesIssued'));, if so it's not working like this, everything works fine when i use CHtml, but with $form widget no. Thanks Ivo